# SQL server calculate and insert with loops

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns "MaxWs", "AvgWs"

and I need to calculate a simple equation on each of them.

MaxWs2m = MaxWs * 0.75

AvgWs2m = AvgWs * 0.75

I created 2 new Columns (MaxWs2m, AvgWs2m) in the table but I need to loop for all record and calculate, insert in the same table.

thanks

Comment: That's a pretty easy update query. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to do it, I can do it by Visual Studio, but here in SQL server

Comment: Loops in SQL are a *very* strong code smell. You don't need them, especially for such a statement. SQL works with entire sets at once, you don't need to process each item in the set individually. Try to think how you would write a `SELECT` statement that returned the values you want. The update statement won't be much different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't

```
UPDATE myTable
SET MaxWs2m = MaxWs * 0.75, AvgWs2m = AvgWs * 0.75
```

exactly what you are looking for? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: yeah, thanks. I didn't know that it's so easy like that, thanks a lot